# PC powers down randomly

Tags: windows-7, hardware-failure, power

My PC powers down and freezes randomly when on windows 7. It works fine on linux. I tried to run memtest and it powered down during(at about 12 %, 0 errors reported till then). On linux mint it runs interrupted.

When playing games on windows, it powers down for sure, but sometimes does it on idle as well.

What tests/diagnostics should I run? Help!

Config:

AMD FX 8120

Radeon HD 7770

Comment: Yeah, but it powered down from memtest. I am talking about the memtest in the grub menu.

Comment: It doesn't fail on memtest. It powers down. Just one stick of RAM I have. I am lost too. It is running linux fine.

Comment: Tried changing the RAM slot. Same issue.

Comment: Any recent changes to Windows setup? Updates, new programs, drivers etc? My random guess if it's windows specific is something maybe overheating it causing motherboard to shut down. Completely random without more info.

Comment: Issue was happening with an older installation. Problem persisted on reinstalling windows.

Comment: Older installation of windows? I'm going to go with driver related then if it works fine in Linux but not windows, and you had some problem on older version of Windows or previous windows install.

Comment: I would perhaps trawl the amd forums. To different or beta install of drivers for gfx, or update to latest

Answer (score 1):

Sudden power downs are usually because of the power source protection triggering - it detects that at least one output voltage is out of bounds and shuts down to protect the pc.

That indicates a faulty or overloaded power supply. If it also does it when idle, I would go with faulty.

If you can, check with a known good power supply, powerfull enough to support your configuration.

Comment: It is a brand new power supply, cooler master thunder 600 watts purchased after the problem was detected. Didn't have an effect.

Comment: Can you try with another video card?

Comment: Don't have one, and don't have onboard video.

Comment: Well, if the PSU is new and good, it will suddenly power off (not shutdown, but loose power, go dark) if the motherboard tells it to or if it goes into overload (at 600w, hard to imagine unless something shorts out). The two things that consume big power are the cpu and a powerfull video card. On the other hand, if it freezes but power remains, that may suggest defective ram or motherboad.